# Adding a button to TOpenPictureDialog

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm using Delphi7 under Windows XP. How would I go about adding a "Delete" toolbutton to the Delphi TOpenPictureDialog component? Is there any way to get the dialog into the Designer to add the button and its behavior?

Comment: Have a look at the source code for TOpenPictureDialog and you have a pretty good sample of how to hack a common dialog around!

Comment: As an aside, the user can delete the selected images by pressing the delete key, or from the context menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can add a new button to the `TOpenPictureDialog` but not getting the dialog into the Designer, you must do it in runtime.

check this sample

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  FDeleteButton   : TSpeedButton;
  FPreviewButton  : TSpeedButton;
begin
    FPreviewButton := TSpeedButton(OpenPictureDialog1.FindComponent('PreviewButton'));
    FDeleteButton  := TSpeedButton.Create(OpenPictureDialog1);
    FDeleteButton.SetBounds(107, 1, 23, 22);
    FDeleteButton.Parent    := FPreviewButton.Parent;
    FDeleteButton.NumGlyphs:=2;        
    FDeleteButton.Glyph.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'BBABORT');
    FDeleteButton.Name    := 'DeleteButton';
    FDeleteButton.OnClick := DeleteBtnClick;
end;

procedure TForm1.DeleteBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   //here you must implement the delete logic 
   ShowMessage('Hello from delete button');
end;
```

and the result is

[image]

Comment: +1. I don't think I could have tried this at all, because on Windows Vista/7 and Delphi 2009, the `TOpenPictureDialog` *is* a standard Windows dialog.

Comment: I think that you can persuade TOpenPictureDialog to revert to a legacy dialog, but it takes a little effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your "own" OpenDialog and inherit this new Class from TOpenPictureDialog. There is an (old) freeware component named "PBOpenPreviewDialog" which does exactly this (from TOpenDialog), maybe you can take that component as an example?

You can find the webpage at: http://bak-o-soft.dk/Delphi/PBFolderDialog.aspx
And a download link for the component here: http://bak-o-soft.dk/Download.asgx.ashx/Delphi/PBFolderDialog.zip

Comment: +1 just to compensate for the downvote (even though I am not sure about the 3rd party control). Personally, I am rather "fed up" (if you pardon my French) with all anonymous downvoting at SO. You can't open your mouth before you get downvoted...

Comment: @Andreas on the other hand this doesn't answer the question. Voting it up doesn't help much either.

Comment: OK, both may be right, i think. I will try to give a more complete answer next time. Thank you.